# GWT Designer Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, uibinder, gwt-designer

I want to use GWT Designer to create UI for web page, i installed SDK and GWT Designer and UIBinder, WindowBuilder. I use eclipse Kepler. It was istalled succesfully, but i can't open a class in Design mode. Get `Internal Error
encountered unexpected internal error.

This could be caused by a bug or by a misconfiguration issue, conflict, partial update, etc.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/TreeLogger;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lcom/google/gwt/dev/cfg/ModuleDef;
```

is it working version available now, or it can't be used?

Comment: There are a few issues sometimes with starting the Designer. You do not mention any versions. Be aware that certain combinations do not work together well. A quick suggestion would be to download and install the GWT 2.6.1 SDK.

Comment: This bug reappeared in Eclipse Luna with GWT-2.7.0. Switching back to GWT-2.6.1 made my day again!

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug from 2.6.0 version. 
The 2.6.1 fixed its.

The 2.6.1 is 
http://www.gwtproject.org/versions.html

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

For Keppler and Maybe Luna

1) Download the SDK 2.61 from official website
2) Unzip 
3) replace '<'Eclipse_Path'>'\plugins\com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.6.0 
* NO change nane folder

Or

Configure as external SDK

Enjoy

Greetings from Nicaragua

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Eclipse solves the problem for Kepler and GWT 2.4